# How do I enable the fast charge USB on my linux machine

Tags: ubuntu, usb, pop-os

I have an Asus G11CB tower PC running Pop OS 20.04 LTS and it has a USB port that supports fast charging (basically 5 watts charging without data transfer) but I need to enable it in the Asus Command Center which is an application available only on Windows 10, is there a way to do the same on a Linux Distro?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the BIOS directly?  (Usually DEL or F2 at boot)

Also, check that your BIOS is up to date.

https://www.asus.com/us/Tower-PCs/G11CB/HelpDesk_BIOS/

Comment: I did ... the BIOS is upto date, the thing is on windows it has to be enabled via the asus command center utility, this disables data transfer and the phone charges like it would on an actual charge brick. This  utility(unsurprisingly) does not exist on any linux distro (at least as far as I have looked on the internet).